# Someone I don't know is sending me test mail. Is this a scam?

Tags: email, scam

In the last couple of weeks I've received several e-mails at my work account (a small research non-profit). The format is similar for all:

- "Test mail" in subject line
- No content in body
- Address follows the format: `[First name][two or three digit number][last name]@gmail.com`
- I do not recognize the names, and as this is a work account, I generally wouldn't be receiving messages from someone's gmail account anyway

This seems suspicious but I can't figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Just delete them and ignore it.  That's really all there is to it.  The "why" can be anywhere from trying to validate an email list to a complete accident or an innocuous start to a scam. The why doesn't really change the response, which is to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are from email aggregators that are testing which emails send a soft/hard bounce response from the service provider. If the user doesn't exist, the service sends back a bounce email to let the sender know. Example: 'User something@somewhere.com doesn't exist.' For businesses this is usually for those annoying business marketing lists.

In general, it can be hard to predict the pattern of text they may use, but you can have your admin setup a bounce response for any email that has just 'test' or 'test email' for the body. It won't be perfect, but it will defeat the few that attempt this with a predictable pattern. Otherwise, just ignore it. If you have an email, you will have spam at some point.